# How do I set the active state for image buttons instead of just focused state with my current code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

First time posting here and new to programming with just 3 days of experience.
I'm having some trouble getting my default button to be `active` instead of just `focused`.  I've attempted to read other posts about this, but my lack of experience makes it hard for me to put 2 and 2 together.

The page is going into squarespace so I'm trying to do it all in one code block.  I don't want the buttons to deactivate when the user clicks on other parts of the website, which it currently happens. (Even if they click on blank areas).

Thank you very much for any advice you can give me.

```css
/* Change Button Size/Border/BG Color And Align To Middle */

.services {
  width: 210px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/G5mn9nY/Services-Buttons-Combined-Big.png") no-repeat;
  /* As all link share the same background-image */
}


/* Set Mouseover Button Text and Current/Active Color */

.services:focus,
.services:hover,
.services:active {
  color: black;
}


/* Position Button Text*/

divtext {
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
}


/* Div Wrapper to format button areas. */

.servicesbuttonwrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* Div Wrapper to format revealed description text. */

.servicestextwrapper {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 32px;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}


/* Change Image rollover position depending On Focus. */

.assets {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.assets:focus,
.assets:hover,
.assets:active {
  background-position: 0 -135px;
}

.viz {
  background-position: 0 -270px;
}

.viz:focus,
.viz:hover,
.viz:active {
  background-position: 0 -405px;
}

.software {
  background-position: 0 -540px;
}

.software:focus,
.software:hover,
.software:active {
  background-position: 0 -675px;
}

.more {
  background-position: 0 -810px;
}

.more:focus,
.more:hover,
.more:active {
  background-position: 0 -945px;
}


/* Hides intitial button descriptions. */

#assets,
#viz,
#software,
#more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Services</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!--Div wrapper so we can format positioning of buttons in CSS-->
  <div class="servicesbuttonwrapper">

    <!--Base buttons plus javascript functions for click behavior.  This used to be <button class> instead of <a href> but I read somewhere this is better...  seems to work ok.-->

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="defaultstate" onclick="show('software');" class="services software">
      <divtext>INTERACTIVE SOFTWARE</divtext>
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('assets');" class="services assets">
      <divtext>3D ASSET CREATION</divtext>
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('viz');" class="services viz">
      <divtext>3D VISUALIZATION</divtext>
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('more');" class="services more">
      <divtext>IMAGE CREATION</divtext>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!--Base description text.-->
  <div class="servicestextwrapper">
    <div id="assets">3D Assets Description.</div>
    <div id="viz">3D Visualization Description.</div>
    <div id="software">Interactive Software Description.</div>
    <div id="more">And More Description.</div>
  </div>

  <!--Javascript function to hide/show elements based on button press.-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function show(elementId) {
      document.getElementById("assets").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("viz").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("software").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("more").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>

  <!--Javascript function to set first button as focus.-->
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("defaultstate").click();
    };
    var linkToFocus = document.getElementById('defaultstate');
    linkToFocus.focus();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

So first thing to note, the :active pseudo element only applies when the user clicks (mouse-down) on something. [You can see it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

The most common method is to apply the css class "active", and have a .active selector on whatever element you want to style.

Right now you have the buttons affected by hover and focus, so when the user clicks outside the button it loses focus.

You can solve this by changing a bit of CSS and javascript. The edited portions are marked by `/* EDIT */`

I would not recommend the last line where I exploit the fact that your function passes in the element ID, and that element ID matches the class of the button that was used to select it. A better way would to have `show` take the Javascript event as argument, then use the event.target to get the a tag clicked on, then use a `getElementById` on something like a `data-target="more"` attribute. This will allow you to change the CSS class without coupling the class to the implementation of the Javascript

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Services</title>
</head>

<style>/* Change Button Size/Border/BG Color And Align To Middle */

    .services {
        width:210px;
        height:135px;
        padding: 0px;
        border:0px;
        outline:0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #999999;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
  background:   url("https://i.ibb.co/G5mn9nY/Services-Buttons-Combined-Big.png") no-repeat; /* As all link share the same background-image */
    }

    
/* Set Mouseover Button Text and Current/Active Color */
/* EDIT */
    .services:focus, .services:hover, .services.active {
        color: black;
    }
    

/* Position Button Text*/
 divtext {
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    }
    
/* Div Wrapper to format button areas. */ 
.servicesbuttonwrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
   }

/* Div Wrapper to format revealed description text. */ 
.servicestextwrapper {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 32px;
    top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}


/* Change Image rollover position depending On Focus. */
    .assets      {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    
    /* EDIT */
    .assets:focus, .assets:hover, .assets.active  {
        background-position: 0 -135px;
    }
    
    
    .viz        {
        background-position: 0 -270px;
    }
    
    /* EDIT */
    .viz:focus, .viz:hover, .viz.active  {
        background-position: 0 -405px;
    }
        
    
    .software   {
        background-position: 0 -540px;
    }
    
    /* EDIT */
    .software:focus, .software:hover, .software.active  {
        background-position: 0 -675px;
    }
    
    .more       {
        background-position: 0 -810px;
    }
    
    /* EDIT */
    .more:focus, .more:hover, .more.active  {
        background-position: 0 -945px;
    }


/* Hides intitial button descriptions. */
#assets, #viz, #software, #more {
    display: none;
} 


</style>

<body>
   
<!--Div wrapper so we can format positioning of buttons in CSS-->
 <div class="servicesbuttonwrapper">

<!--Base buttons plus javascript functions for click behavior.  This used to be <button class> instead of <a href> but I read somewhere this is better...  seems to work ok.--> 

     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="defaultstate" onclick="show('software');" class="services software"><divtext>INTERACTIVE SOFTWARE</divtext></a>
           
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('assets');" class="services assets"><divtext>3D ASSET CREATION</divtext></a>
                
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('viz');" class="services viz"><divtext>3D VISUALIZATION</divtext></a>
                
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('more');" class="services more"><divtext>IMAGE CREATION</divtext></a>
   </div>
   
<!--Base description text.--> 
   <div class="servicestextwrapper">
        <div id="assets">3D Assets Description.</div>
  <div id="viz">3D Visualization Description.</div>
  <div id="software">Interactive Software Description.</div>
  <div id="more">And More Description.</div>
   </div>   
   
<!--Javascript function to hide/show elements based on button press.--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* EDIT */
    function show(elementId) {
        document.getElementById("assets").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("viz").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("software").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("more").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "block";
        
        // get a list of the buttons with ".services" class
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".services");
        
        for(let button of buttons) {
          // remove ".active" class
          button.classList.remove("active");
        }
        
        // add the active class to element button specified by argument
        document.querySelector("." + elementId).classList.add("active");
    }  
   </script>
   
<!--Javascript function to set first button as focus.--> 
<script>
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("defaultstate").click();
};
var linkToFocus = document.getElementById('defaultstate');
linkToFocus.focus();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your post, this is very informative.  I don't fully understand the last paragraph but that's not your fault, I'm just new.  I am going to look into more information about it and try to learn more about passing data with 'show'.  most of the code was cobbled together from examples on the web and some trial and error, but you've given me some direction on where to look to improve.  Thank you so much!